# How to locate simple words amongst compound/simple words using Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, trie

I have a list of words that have both 'simple' and 'compound' words in them, and would like to implement an algorithm that prints out a list of words without the compound words that are made up of the simple words.

Sampel input:

```
chat, ever, snapchat, snap, salesperson, per, person, sales, son, whatsoever, what, so
```

Desired output:

```
chat, ever, snap, per, sales, son, what, so
```

I have written the following, but am stuck as to how to take it on from here:

```
private static String[] find(String[] words) {

    ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> r1 = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String s: words){
        alist.add(s);
    }
    Collections.sort(alist,new Comparator<String>() {

        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

            return o1.length()-o2.length();
        }
    });

    int count= 0;
    for(int i=0;i<alist.size();i++){
        String check = alist.get(i);
        r1.add(check);
        for(int j=i+1;j<alist.size();j++){

            String temp = alist.get(j);
            //System.out.println(check+" "+temp);
            if(temp.contains(check) ){

                alist.remove(temp);

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(r1.toString());
    String res[] = new String[r1.size()];
    for(String i:words){
        if(r1.contains(i)){
            res[count++] = i;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Any guidance/insight or suggestions to a better approach would be appreciated.

Comment: An approach could be to examine the morphology of the word. It'll be more complicated than creating a trie as suggested in the answers, but it may be an approach you may be interested in,  Here's a research paper you may find interesting: http://www.biolinguistics.uqam.ca/Fiorentino_Poeppel_2007.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I tried to go through your code, looks like "son" is not in your output. I believe it failed because of this line:

```
if(temp.contains(check)) { <-- wrong check.
    alist.remove(temp); 
}
```

So instead of simply checking if temp.contains(check), you should have a small loop that does the following:

1. does temp start with `check`?
2. if 1) passed, then let temp = temp.substring(check.length), then go back to 1) again, until temp == "";

Another implementation would be setting up a trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and check using that?

1. sort the word list based on word length
2. foreach of the word, if the word is not in the trie, add it to the trie. otherwise, this is either a dup or a compound word
3. output the trie into a list of words using DFS.

step 1 make sure that when u check for a compound word, its simple word is already in the trie.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try to find the bug in your code, but rather wrote my own impl using a simple loop and a recursive helper method:

```
private static String[] find(String[] array) {
    Set<String> words = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array));
    Set<String> otherWords = new HashSet<>(words);
    for (Iterator<String> i = words.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        String next = i.next();
        otherWords.remove(next);
        if (isCompound(next, otherWords)) {
            i.remove();
        } else {
            otherWords.add(next);
        }
    }
    return words.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
}

private static boolean isCompound(String string, Set<String> otherWords) {
    if (otherWords.contains(string)) {
        return true;
    }
    for (String word : otherWords) {
        if (string.startsWith(word)) {
            return isCompound(string.replaceAll("^" + word, ""), otherWords);
        }
        if (string.endsWith(word)) {
            return isCompound(string.replaceAll(word + "$", ""), otherWords);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/cw7iUM).

This produces your desired output, which requires preserving word order.

#### Explanation

A compound word is comprised solely of other words in the list. Importantly, this implies that compound words both *start* and *end* with other words. Rather than search for other words at every position in a word, we can use this fact to only check the start/end , which greatly simplifies the code.

Thus: for each word in the list, if it start/ends with *another* word, remove that word and repeat the process until there's nothing left, at which point you know the word is compound.

A set of "other words", which is the full set with the current word removed, is passed to the helper method to further simplify the code.

Comment: ♦ Sorry but do you mind adding some explanations/comments for the implementation? Trying to learn. Thank you and will accept/upvote afterwards.

Comment: @JoKo is that explanation enough?

Comment: ♦ Not sure how I missed it this. Really appreciate the input, and I gave it an attempt, but actually gave a different output. Did it work on your end?

Comment: @joko yes, it works. There was a missing return statement, which I fixed, and I've added a [link to live demo](https://ideone.com/cw7iUM), which shows it working.

Comment: ♦ Thank you! In need of a few clarifications. But what does `Iterator<String> i = words.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ` in the for loop? And what do `"^"` and `"$"` mean? If you can provide short comment snippets for each line would be extremely help and clear a lot of things. Thank you in advance

Comment: @joko read the "Iterators" section on the [Collections interface tutorial page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html). In regex, `^` means *start* and `$` means *end* - visit [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info/index.html) to learn about regex. Both topics are subjects in themselves; can't be covered in a comment.

Comment: ♦ Got it. Thank you for the clarification. Before I accept the answer and upvote, would there be a way to implement it without regex?

Comment: ♦ Also what does `.stream()` and `String[]::new` do? Researched it but couldn't find it. And why did you choose to use one as LinkedHashSet and other as just simple HashSet?

Comment: @joko again, what you're asking covers a lot of ground. You really need to read up on Java 8, but see [javadoc for `.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--). `toArray()` takes a `Function<Integer, T[]>` and `String[]::new` is a method reference to the constructor `new String[n]`. `LinkedHashSet` iterates in insertion order, which is needed to preserve word order for the result as per your inferred specs. `HashSet` was sufficient to hold the set of visited words.

Comment: Also, can be done without regex: `string.substring(word.length())` and `string.substring(0, string.length() - word.length())` instead of the 2 calls to `replaceAll()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my straightforward n^2 solution:

```
static String[] simpleWords(String[] words) {
    String[] result;
    HashSet<Integer> map = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String word = words[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            if(j != i) {
                word = word.replaceAll(words[j], "");
            }
        }
        if(!word.equals("")) {
            map.add(i);
        }
    }
    result = new String[map.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for(int index: map) {
        result[i] = words[index];
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```